# How to attach images (JPG/ PNG etc) from assets into a pdf

Tags: image, flutter, pdf

I'm having trouble with using the Image widget from the pdf library

Current version:
pdf: ^3.3.0

Code:

```
final imageA = PdfImage.file(
  pdf.document,
  bytes: File('lib/Images/rocket14.jpg').readAsBytesSync(),
);

child: pw.Image(pw.ImageImage(pdfimageA)),
```

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'PdfImage' is not a subtype of type 'Image'

I have absolutely no idea on how to parse a Pdfimage into an image.

Using

```
 Future<MemoryImage> convtoImage(String name) async => pw.MemoryImage((await rootBundle.load('assets/img/$name.jpg')).buffer.asUint8List(),);
```

results in a catch 22 where

> error: A value of type 'MemoryImage' can't be returned from the function 'convtoImage' because it has a return type of 'Future<MemoryImage>'. (return_of_invalid_type at [scanrecopdfmaker] lib\main.dart:490)

If I were to make it a return type of memimage, it will prompt me to turn it back into a future.

I also tried this, but it never updates the value so it remains null

```
Future<Uint8List> convtoImage(String name) async {
   ///1
   var a = await rootBundle.load('lib/Images/$name.jpg');
   Uint8List data = (await rootBundle.load('lib/Images/rocket14.jpg'))
       .buffer
       .asUint8List();
  // print("data IS $data");

   // var b = pw.MemoryImage(a.buffer.asUint8List());

  return  data;
 }
 var done;
  var tempa =  convtoImage('rocket14').whenComplete(() {
    print("done");
  }).then((value) => done=value);

print("AA IS $tempa");
  print("BIS $done");

  while(done == null){
    print(done);
   }

  print("Finito");
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use rootBundle to load image from assets

```
pw.MemoryImage(
(await rootBundle.load('assets/img/your_image.jpg')).buffer.asUint8List(),
);
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the asset in `pubspec.yaml` too

Comment: Tried that but had a few errors. updated my question. i must be missing something

Comment: You must be getting type error in function convToImage because it has return type of Future<MemoryImage> instead of Future<pw.MemoryImage>

Answer (score 3):

```
final ByteData image = await rootBundle.load('assets/image/your_image.jpg');

Uint8List imageData = (image).buffer.asUint8List();
```

An example to use it:

```
pw.Container(
    width: 50.0,
    height: 50.0,
    child: pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(logoData))
)
```